# How do I create a Data Extension via the SOAP API?

Tags: api, soap, dataextensions

I'm having trouble creating an API call that will create a Data Extension. I'm referring to the docs located [here](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_data_extension_using_web_service_api/).

Using this request:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "SOAPAction: Retrieve" -d "$(cat xmlrequest.txt)" "https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx"
```

Where the contents of xmlrequestl.txt are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header>
    <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <UsernameToken>
        <Username>jared@lytics.io</Username>
        <Password>#OUR_VALID_PASSWORD#</Password>
      </UsernameToken>
    </Security>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Options></Options>
    <Objects xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xsi:type="ns1:DataExtension">
        <CustomerKey>TestDataExtensionFromAPI</CustomerKey>
        <Name>TestDataExtensionFromAPI</Name>
        <IsSendable>true</IsSendable>
        <SendableDataExtensionField>
            <CustomerKey>EmailAddress_Key</CustomerKey>
            <Name>EmailAddress</Name>
            <FieldType>EmailAddress</FieldType>
        </SendableDataExtensionField>
        <SendableSubscriberField>
            <Name>Email Address</Name>
            <Value></Value>
        </SendableSubscriberField>
        <Fields>
            <Field>
                <CustomerKey>EmailAddress_Key</CustomerKey>
                <Name>EmailAddress</Name>
                <FieldType>EmailAddress</FieldType>
            </Field>
            <Field>
                <CustomerKey>ChannelUser_Key</CustomerKey>
                <Name>ChannelUser</Name>
                <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
            </Field>
            <Field>
                <CustomerKey>ChannelUser_EmailAddress_Key</CustomerKey>
                <Name>ChannelUser_EmailAddress</Name>
                <FieldType>EmailAddress</FieldType>
            </Field>
            <Field>
                <CustomerKey>Demographic_Address_Key</CustomerKey>
                <Name>Demographic_Address</Name>
                <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
            </Field>
        </Fields>
    </Objects>
</CreateRequest>
```

When I do this, I receive a 100 Continue paired with a 200 OK, but the body of the response indicates a problem:

```
<OverallStatus>Error</OverallStatus>
<RequestID>1faa970c-3296-4ec9-8e2c-3e56619f9d42</RequestID>
```

How can I correct my request?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Right after I posted this, I realized the problem was that I was using a SOAPAction of Retrieve, rather than Create. Fixing this resolved the issue.